# tar doesn't find a file in an archive, depending on the command used to try to extract it

Tags: centos, tar

I have been trying to extract a file from a tgz archive for hours.

Using `tar -xzf my.tgz ./file.sh` extract the file properly. However, an installation script I am using is extracting the file differently, using `tar xfzO my.tgz ./file.sh > /tmp/file.sh`.

In the first case, tar complete correctly, extracting the file as intended. In the second case however, it output a message informing me that ./file.sh was not found in the archive. Strangely, `tar --list ./file.sh -f my.tgz` output that the file doesn't exist, but then why is it successfully extracted the first time ?

How can I extract my file, using the second method properly ? Why is tar not finding it, despite it being there ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the preceding `./`?

Comment: Did you try to use a correct command line? Your command line tells a correct TAR to open `zO` as archive.

Answer (score 1):

The order of commands to `tar` is significant. Specifically: the argument directly after the f must be the tar-archive. Try:

```
tar xzOf my.tgz ./file.sh > /tmp/file.sh
```